# Sticky Footer is Not Giving Sticky Behavior

Tags: html, css

[christianselig.com/contact](http://christianselig.com/contact.html)

For some reason the footer only sticks half way up the page on this one page, but all the others are seemingly okay. I've looked for ages and can't peg the reason.

I've put the relevant HTML and CSS below, and anything more is obviously available.

HTML:

```
                <div class="alt-contact">
                    <p>Prefer manual contacting? <a href="mailto:me@example">Email me.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- This div corresponds to the content wrapper div above -->

            <div class="footer-wrapper">
                <div class="footer">
                    <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2012 Christian Selig</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-wrapper {
    background: #f7f7f7; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f7f7f7), color-stop(100%,#d6d6d6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#d6d6d6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#d6d6d6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#d6d6d6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f7f7f7 0%,#d6d6d6 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7f7f7', endColorstr='#d6d6d6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 8px 0 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

    .footer {
        color: #808080;
        clear: both;
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        margin: auto;
        width: 900px; 
    }
```

Comment: Dont get you. The footer sticks fine at the bottom?

Comment: The footer sticks to the bottom of the document, not the window. When your document is less than the height of the browser window (because you don't have enough content), the footer will not appear to stick to the bottom.

Comment: Please make your question less specific to you, and more general to the concept of sticky footers, so that maybe another user may find it helpful. Also, please add detail, we have no idea what the first two sentences meant.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? I see the footer on the contact page sticking to the bottom in Chrome, FF, IE and Opera.

Comment: If you have problem what @MikeRobinson has mentioned you should try [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) or you can set a `position:fixed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Your `html` has no `height` given to it, so it's only as tall as the `body` pushes it. Note, in IE8 and less you have to use "tricker" solutions like R[yan Fait's Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    margin: 0 auto -142px; 
}
.footer, .push {
    /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    height: 142px; 
}

/* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
   http://ryanfait.com/       */
```

I've used it; it works. It gives you headaches, though, because it essentially takes `margin` and `padding` flexibility away from you. Which can be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because `position: absolute;` doesn't make sticky footers. If you want a sticky footer, you need to use `position: fixed;`. this will make the footer stay in the same spot relative to the browser window, as opposed to the next relevant parent object.

Good Luck,
-Brian

Comment: Really? Position: absolute; ? what happens when the content overflows?